# Client-Server in an Android Application

Tags: java, android, sockets, client, rmi

I'm trying to do a local Java server and an Android Application that connects to the server. I searched a little and i found out that i can use WebSocket in order to create the connection, but i didn't find anything about rmi registry. I tried to use it, but i can't get it work, so i had to use WebSocket and this code

```
>               int port=2111;       
>               try {
>               ServerSocket servSock;
>               servSock = new ServerSocket(port);
>               System.out.println("[+] Server ready.");
>               
>               while(true) 
>               {
>                    //Assigns a new thread to any client connected
>                   Socket socket = servSock.accept();
>                   new MySocketServer(socket).start();
>               }
>           
>               }catch (IOException e) {
>                   e.printStackTrace();}
```

Is there something like rmi for android applications too, or must i use WebSocket for the connection? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I suggest you take a look in a library called KryoNet. I used before and it's awesome. https://code.google.com/p/kryonet/#Remote_Method_Invocation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a little network background study for this... You can use TCP or UDP for transport packages. Use SOCKET for TCP and DATAGRAM for UDP its a lot faster than TCP but less connection oriented.

On Android side use Threading for network communication otherwise you get an error for blocking the UI thread.

Search the google there are lot of example JAVA/ANDROID TCP/UDP server-client example

Answer (score 0):

You can also use http protocol to implement the long connection. Also. there are many MBaaS platform, such as parse,stackMob. These platform provides many open APIs, you can invoke these API directly

Answer (score 0):

Try use Netty framework (http://netty.io).  I used a lot for all my client-serever programming.  Netty is nice for the server side.  For android, I use HttpClient when no push notification is requiered from the server.  If you need push notitications, visit: https://code.google.com/p/android-random/ (KeepAliveService).  It is a good start.